# Copy-pasting cells that change column for every 4 cells pasted

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to copy, let's say 12 cells that are listed in a column, to 4 columns that for every 4 items change row to the one below?

[image: Example]

Comment: could you maybe post example data and an illustration what you want the result to be. With this little information it is very hard to identify what you want

Comment: I have added an example image, does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you happy to use a formula to achieve your result? (instead of copy/paste)

This formula can be put in all cells of the destination table.
You'll need to adjust the source anchors (`$B$3`), and the destination anchors (`$F$3`) and width (`4`) according to your spreadsheet.

Even if you want "*values*" in the destination cells rather than "*formulas*", this is still probably the best approach... use the formula and then flatten the cells to values (use Copy / Paste Special → Values).

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(((ROW()-ROW($F$3))*4)+(COLUMN()-COLUMN($F$3))+ROW($B$3),COLUMN($B$3)))
```

1. Produce the source row

   - `ROW()-ROW($F$3)` - get the zero-based row of the destination table

     - `ROW()` - row of "*this*" cell
     - `ROW($F$3)` - first row of the destination table
   - `*4` - multiply by number of columns in destination table
   - `+(COLUMN()-COLUMN($F$3))` - add the column of the destination table

     - `COLUMN()` - column of "*this* cell, numeric and 1-based
     - `COLUMN($F$3)` - first column of the destination table
   - `+ROW($B$3)` - add the row of the source table

     - `ROW($B$3)` - first row of the source data
2. Get the address of the source cell

   - `ADDRESS(..., COLUMN($B$3))` - row from step 1, and source column
3. Get the value by address

   - `INDIRECT(...)` - using the address from step 2

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't know it would turn out to be so complicated, but I will definitely use this.